# Excluding groups from a resultset using criteria in that resultset

Tags: sql, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008.

We are given a Code, say 020286 that gives us a starting resultset.
Starting data:

```
Code    L   R   G
020286  2   703 1
030383  3   6   0
031847  4   5   0
021932  7   10  0
022499  8   9   0
020068  229 310 1
020866  231 306 1
020524  232 241 0
030772  233 234 0
031787  235 236 0
031859  237 238 0
031947  239 240 0
020964  242 323 1
021215  253 342 1
030728  343 344 0
020990  345 346 0
022521  347 354 0
```

Now I want to exclude rows whose L is between L and R of any rows whose G=1 (in the same resultset) excepting the given Code (essentially do "L between L and R" for all G=1 except the given Code), while still keeping all G=1.
Expected results:

```
Code    L   R   G
020286  2   703 1
030383  3   6   0
031847  4   5   0
021932  7   10  0
022499  8   9   0
020068  229 310 1
020866  231 306 1
020964  242 323 1
021215  253 342 1
030728  343 344 0
020990  345 346 0
022521  347 354 0
```

Here is a table var with starting data.

```
declare @t table (Code nvarchar(10),L int, R int, G int)
insert into @t (Code, L, R, G)
select '020286',2,703,1 union
select '030383',3,6,0 union
select '031847',4,5,0 union
select '021932',7,10,0 union
select '022499',8,9,0 union
select '020068',229,610,1 union
select '020866',231,396,1 union
select '020524',232,241,0 union
select '030772',233,234,0 union
select '031787',235,236,0 union
select '031859',237,238,0 union
select '031947',239,240,0 union
select '020964',242,383,1 union
select '021215',253,342,1 union
select '030728',343,344,0 union
select '020990',345,346,0 union
select '022521',347,354,0

select * from @t
```

Comment: Can you tell me why this record is not selected: `031859  237 238 0`

Comment: That row's L is between L and R for both 020068 and 020866; we want to exclude L's between L and R where G=1 (except given Code of 020286).

Comment: How come `030383  3   6   0` is selected? It is only between the L and R of the given row! I do not understand

Comment: "essentially do "L between L and R" for all G=1 except the given Code", the given code is not looked at for exclusions.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the given code is identifyable somehow, so I'll assume there's a variable available containing it, which I'm calling @given:

```
DECLARE @given nvarchar(10)
SELECT @given = '020286'
```

First identify the L of rows where G=1 and which are not the given code:

```
SELECT L INTO #L FROM @t WHERE G=1 AND Code <> @given;
```

Now we need to join each pair of consecutive values in #L into rows in a new table which can then be used to work out which rows in @t we dont want. There's a few ways of doing this, but this one is pretty easy and simple to follow:

```
SELECT L as [Low], Cast(0 as int) as [High] 
INTO #Pairs 
FROM #L 
WHERE L < (SELECT Max(L) FROM #L);

UPDATE #Pairs SET [High] = (SELECT Min(L) FROM #L WHERE L > [Low]);
```

Now remove the unwanted rows in @t:

```
DELETE t
FROM @t t CROSS JOIN #Pairs p
WHERE L > p.[Low] AND L < p.[High]
```

What's left should be correct:

```
SELECT * FROM @t ORDER BY L
```

Comment: DELETE with a CROSS JOIN !

Comment: I always forget about Cross Join...  anytime you think "for each row" think CROSS JOIN.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Using your stated criteria:

> Exclude rows whose L is between L and R of any rows whose G=1 (in the same resultset) excepting the given Code (essentially do "L between L and R" for all G=1 except the given Code), while still keeping all G=1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @t 
WHERE G = 1 
      OR NOT(L >= (SELECT MIN(L) FROM @t WHERE G = 1 AND NOT Code = '020286') 
             AND L <= (SELECT MAX(R) FROM @t WHERE G = 1 AND NOT Code = '020286'))
```

However, your expected results do not appear to match your stated criteria.  You appear to be saying (for this data set and criteria) that you want to exclude `G<>1` rows with `L` between 229 (`MIN(L)` where `Code <> '020286'`) and 610 (`MAX(R)` where `Code <> '020286'`), but these rows don't appear to match the apparent intent of your stated criteria:

```
CODE    L   R   G
030728  343 344 0
020990  345 346 0
022521  347 354 0
```

In fact, it would appear that your criteria is actually:

> Exclude rows whose L is between L and R of any **previous** rows whose G=1 (in the same resultset) excepting the given Code (essentially do "L between L and R" for **the previous** G=1 except the given Code), while still keeping all G=1:

```
WITH Criteria
AS (SELECT Code, L, R, G
    FROM @t
    WHERE G = 1)
SELECT T.Code, T.L, T.R, T.G
FROM @t AS T
INNER JOIN Criteria
    ON T.L >= Criteria.L 
         AND T.L <= Criteria.R 
         AND T.G <> 1 
         AND Criteria.Code <> '020286'
UNION ALL
SELECT Code, L, R, G
FROM Criteria
ORDER BY 1
```